# Car Axle Mesh Deformation Problem

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting, vertex-weights

I am working on Car Suspension and want to move the axle with wheels upward and downward movements but the Axle Housing of an axle moves separately when i move the bone "BoneHub_FL" upward or downward, the axle housing is not deforming properly so how can i fix this issue, what is the proper way of doing it. Any help will be appreciated.

[image][image][image][image][image]